# Database AWS CloudFormation Wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress, amazon-web-services

So I am on the process of moving my WP website to AWS.
I started by using AWS CloudFormation (1) which configures it for me. A new version of wordpress is instaled.

Two questions:

1. Where is my database?
2. How can I populate it with my backup .sql
   file?

(1)http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/

Answer (score 1):

If you log into the web console, you can view all of the services associated with the cloud formation.  Databases are found under service > Database > RDS (most likely MySQL for your case).

You should check out EC2 instance to make sure everythign you need is running.  This is also the place to edit security groups that become very important during testing.

You can connect to the database following this [aws guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html).